# Upper bound for the function $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}$ when $x\neq k\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\epsilon\in (0, \pi/2)$. Suppose that, $x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[n\pi +\epsilon, (n+1)\pi -\epsilon]$. What is an upper bound for the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3x}?$$

It is enough for me to know that it is bounded from above by a constant.

I would say that it is bounded by $1$ using the fact that $-1\le\cos x\le 1$ and $-1\le\sin x\le 1$, but I am not sure about that.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not bounded. There are points where $\cos x$ is close to $1$ and $\sin x$ is positive and  close to $0$.

Comment: Does this look bounded? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+cos%28x%29%2Fsin%28x%29%5E3

Comment: With your argument, $\tan(x)$ would also be a bounded function.

Comment: You are right, sorry. And if I consider $x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[n\pi +\epsilon, (n+1)\pi -\epsilon]$? Here $\epsilon\in(0, \pi/2)$. In this case I can sai it is bounded?

Comment: Yes, you can. Because then $|\sin(x)|$ is bounded *below* by a positive constant.

Comment: @MartinR I edit the question. Could you please give some details?

Comment: $\frac 1 {\sin \epsilon}$ is an upper bound there.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you give some more details? I don't feel so familiar with that.

Comment: @User1010: Do you see that $|\sin(x)| \ge \sin(\epsilon)> 0$ for those $x$?

Comment: @MartinR actually no, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the question in your comment:Using the fact that $|\sin (n \pi+x)|=|\sin x|$ we see we only need a lower bound for $|\sin x|$ on $[\epsilon, \pi-\epsilon]$. But $\sin x$ is increasing on $[\epsilon, \frac {\pi} 2]$ and decreasing on $[\frac {\pi} 2, \pi-\epsilon]$. Now it is not difficult to see that $|\sin x| \geq |\sin \epsilon]$ on $[\epsilon, \pi-\epsilon]$. Hence, $|\frac {\cos x} {\sin^{3}(x)}| \leq \frac  1{\sin^{3}\epsilon}$.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, but the function fro which I need the upper bound is $\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3 x}$.

Comment: @User1010 The upper bound you are looking for is $\frac  1{\sin^{3}\epsilon}$. If you are worried about the sign of the denominator note that $f(x) \leq |f(x)|$.